# How to declare and access extern symbols in rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand all the pieces in declaring and accessing extern symbols in RUST.
Here is an example.

```
extern {
      static foreign_symbol: ui32;
}
```

Keyword **extern** is to say linker that the symbol is outside of this binary.
Keyword **static** is for lifetime to last forever.
The type **ui32**, should match the definition from foreign source.

Here are the questions:
a. What about the mutability of this external variable?
b. How to initialize this extern variable?
c. Most of the extern usage sample code have extern -C. What is the difference between using extern & extern -C ?
d. I need to access my risc-v assembly function from rust code. What is the calling convention for this?

Comment: Please focus your questions. Each SO question should correspond to a single question. Also, avoid questions of the kind "I've read in the documentation that [...], is it true?" as the only possible answer is "yes".

Comment: @BlackBeans Thanks for your comment & removed it.

Comment: As @BlackBeans said, please only ask one question per SO question.

Answer (score 2):

**Here I'm answering my own question after reading & trying out.**

a. extern variables aren't mutable by default unless marked as mutable in declaration.

b. extern variables can't be initialized and can't even have a body.

```
  extern "C" {
        static  _stack_start: u32 = 20;
    }
```

It throws the following error -

> extern` blocks define existing foreign statics and statics inside of
> them cannot have a body

c. extern C adopts C calling convention vs extern can be one of "systems" or "C" etc (https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html )

d. Couldn't find the answer yet. But as of Aug, 2020 it was unspecified (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/where-can-i-find-the-rust-calling-convention-for-risc-v/47573)